# 4-bit parallel data bus using DMA and GPIO on STM32?

Tags: stm32, gpio, vga, dma

It's possible to generate 8 or 16-bit parallel output on an STM32 by using DMA to transfer from a buffer to the ODR register of a GPIO port, by transferring either a byte or a word at a time. However I'm wondering if there is a way to transfer a half-byte at a time to 4 GPIO pins, and generate 4-bit parallel output?

I know this could be done by bit-banging easily enough but I want to know if it can be done by the DMA controller. Or alternatively, is there a component available which will take 8 bits and generate 2 * 4 bits, sort of like an array of 4 2-bit shift registers in parallel?

The application for this would be a simple VGA controller with 3 1-bit RGB signals plus one control signal. So I would have an in-memory frame buffer of pixels, each byte containing 2 pixels.

---

Thinking about this, it should be possible by using a scanline buffer, and expanding each half-byte in the frame buffer a byte in the scanline buffer, with only the first 4 bits set.

Or alternatively, each byte in the scanline could be assigned using a 4-bit palette index lookup. Which would yield 8-bit colour with a 16-colour palette.

The expense would be some CPU processing before each scanline.

Comment: Sounds like quad SPI might do it but only particular STM32F4 series chips provide it.

Comment: Quad SPI won't do what you want. It's pretty specific to serial flash chips.

Comment: If you don't mind wasting some RAM you can DMA data to the Bit Set/Reset Register (BSRR) which allows you to atomically set or reset individual bits by a single write operation. (Note though that with 16 bit DMA you cannot set *and* reset bits at the same time; this requires two 16-bit transfers, so a small delay between setting and resetting bits.)